# The “HP t100 Zero Client” or the “HP t200 Zero Client” can support a 1920x1080 37" monitor?

Tags: hdtv, high-definition, thin-client

I want to know if someone have tried the "HP t100 Zero Client" or the "HP t200 Zero Client" and knows if can support a 1920x1080 on 37" monitor.

Comment: You can look this up in the specifications of the monitor. Please [do some effort](http://superuser.com/questions/how-to-ask) before asking questions...

Comment: This question is low quality and way too localized. Please read the [Super User FAQ](http://superuser.com/faq) *before* posting next time..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the [t200](http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/Document.jsp?lang=en&cc=us&taskId=120&prodSeriesId=5171156&prodTypeId=12454&objectID=c03050831) has `maximum video resolution 2048 x 1152, 32-bit` so it **can**
the [t100](http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/Document.jsp?objectID=c01996219&lang=en&cc=us&taskId=101&prodSeriesId=4084245&prodTypeId=12454) has `maximum video resolution 1280 x 1024 (standard screen); 1440 x 900 (widescreen) 32bit` so it **cannot**